# Laravel and algolia, ignore array if null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, algolia

I have this code:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $data = $this->toArray();
    $data['_geoloc'] = $this->_geoloc->toArray();
    $data['address'] = $this->address->toArray();
    return $data;
}
```

However sometimes $data['entities'] is null therefore throwing me an error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Call to a member function toArray() on null
```

Is there any  way to by-pass that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check elements if they exist and not null before call methods on them, like this:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $data = $this->toArray();
    $data['_geoloc'] = !empty($this->_geoloc) ? $this->_geoloc->toArray() : null;
    $data['address'] = !empty($this->address) ? $this->address->toArray() : '';
    return $data;
```

}

Also `$this->toArray();` will convert the model instance to an array with all relations. So you need to load them like: `$this->load('_geoloc', 'address');` and call only `$data = $this->toArray();`

Answer (score 1):

I assume address is a relation to another table.

toArray() will convert it, if it was loaded before

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $this->address;

    $data = $this->toArray();

    return $data;
}
```

Is _geoloc also a relation to another table?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $data = $this->toArray();


    $data['_geoloc'] = $this->_geoloc->toArray();
    $data['address'] = $this->address->toArray();

    print('<pre style="color:red;">');
    print_r($data);
    print('</pre>');
    exit;

    return $data;

}
```

Hope help for you !!!

Comment: $data = $this->toArray(); is never empty, but $data['address'] is

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas Please show your result set for $data['_geoloc'] and $data['address']

Comment: how if it's empty?

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas : Please check my updated answer and just show your result set for $data

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd You should use `dd($var)`, it would be easier